# Different colour for react-table headers

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Having trouble with styling table created by react-table library.

Please find the design below.
[image]

Table is created the way it is shown in documentation. Is it possible to colour headers as shown in design?

Thank you in advance

P.S.
Here is the code snippet from documentation
[image]

To create headers I need to create an array. So i cant change style for a specific header (actually I can provide element to render, but it will be rendered inside the  element)

Comment: Please provide a relevant code snippet from the documentation.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson please check the screenshot. I have provided some info as well, idk if it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [**this**](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/data-driven-classes-and-styles?from-embed), there are class names added to the data where the data should be styled differently. I think that's what you need.

Comment: This is great, but having typescript error "Property 'className' does not exist on type 'HeaderGroup<object>'."

Comment: @SergeNajimov, I found out that you actually don't need to add a className to the headergroup, but the add style object to the style prop. Check lines 133 and 167 in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-wave-9nsfy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: oh, thank you. will try it and let you know

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. `INVALID_REQUEST - No commit found for SHA: master`

Answer (score 0):

You can use any react component or JSX to display content in column headers, cells and footers.

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: () => (
      <span>
        <i className="fa-tasks" /> Progress
      </span>
    )
  }
]
```

kindly check on this link for further details

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#custom-cell-header-and-footer-rendering

Comment: I did not want to create new element with absolute style. but i believe this is the only workaround. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Had to use a workaround.
As Taha Jamil mentioned you can any JSX to render inside of the Header. By adjusting some styles you will get something like this:

```
{
  Header: () => {
    return(
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "red",
          position: "absolute",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          top: "0px",
          left: "0px",
          padding: "12px 20px",
        }}
      >
        Title
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Not the best solution, but works

Comment: Please don't provide code in a picture.